# Zip 2 Collections based on a value in Java

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, iterable

I have 2 `Collection`s of some objects `A` and `B` that have a field `key`. I'd like to zip those 2 collections based on that field to have tuples of objects A and B with the same `key`.

From:

```
Collection<A> a;
Collection<B> b;
```

To:

```
List<Pair<A, B>> ab; // where A and B have the same key field
```

What I am doing now is constructing a `Map<KeyType, Pair<A, B>>` manually and creating a list from that but I am sure there is a better way to do that.

**Edit** (explain how I am creating the map):

```
Map<KeyType, Pair<A, B>> keyToAandB = new HashMap<>();

a.stream()
    .forEach(aa -> keyToAandB.put(
        aa.getKey(),
        Pair.of(aa, null)));

b.stream()
    .forEach(bb -> keyToAandB.put(
        bb.getKey(),
        Pair.of(
            keyToAandB.get(bb.getKey()).getFirst(),
            bb)));
```

Comment: to make the question clearer, could you state how are you creating the `Map<KeyType, Pair<A, B>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very different from your solution, but slightly cleaner IMO:

```
Map<KeyType, A> keyToA = a.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getKey, Function.identity()));

List<Pair<A, B>> ab = b.stream()
    .map(bb -> Pair.of(keyToA.get(bb.getKey()), bb))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you're willing to suffer quadratic performance, you can use a nested stream:

```
List<Pair<A, B>> ab = a.stream()
    .map(aa -> Pair.of(aa, b.stream()
        .filter(bb -> bb.getKey().equals(aa.getKey()))
        .findAny()
        .get()))   // will throw exception if missing
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: yep slightly cleaner. I was wondering if there is a method to not use an intermediary map but I don't think so